# Functional Programming: Numpy Vectorizable Function to Create an Expected Values Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, functional-programming

I want to run a chi-squared statistical test against some categorical data counts - but to do that, I need to calculate the expected values for each cell of an array matching my observed results array.

The pseudo code for the content of a each element e in the array is

```
e = column_sum * row_sum / total_sum
```

I've written a function that will convert an array into its expected-values counterpart:

```
def gen_expected(a_array):
    new_array = np.zeros(a_array.shape,dtype=float)
    for ri,r in enumerate(a_array):
        for ci,c in enumerate(a_array.T):
            new_array[ri,ci]=(c.sum()*r.sum()/a_array.sum())
    return new_array
```

This works well enough, but I'd really like to adopt a more functional approach and define a function at the element level that I can vectorise (using `np.vectorize`) and apply without performing any potentially expensive loops in code.

My problem is that the information required at element level isn't enough to generate the required output - I'm trying to figure out how to access the aggregate sum values from within the (presumably) element-level function - is this simply not possible, or is there a functional pattern I'm not yet aware of that fits this type of aggregate-reliant condition?

Comment: "I'd really like to adopt a more functional approach and define a function at the element level that I can vectorise (using `np.vectorize`)" - no, no, no! `np.vectorize` is not efficient. It only gets you the behavior, not the speed. It's basically a wrapper around a `for` loop.

Comment: People keep falling into that trap because they hear "you should vectorize your code", see `np.vectorize`, and think, "hey, that sounds like it solves my problem!" They don't get far enough into the docs to see "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: When people say you should vectorize your code, they mean something completely different, something that unfortunately doesn't appear in the first few Google hits for `numpy vectorize`.

Comment: :) ahh I see - that sounds very familiar indeed - ok, so that helps put some of my misunderstandings into context - so thankyou for that - can you recommend any deeper and more appropriate approaches?

Comment: Having taken your advice and googling further, I find reference to `ufuncs` which might be promising - as per here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#methods ) - I'll research a little further and attach onto here for reference.

Comment: Look for operations that take entire arrays and operate elementwise or along specified axes. For example, `sum` can compute all sums along an axis of an array in one call, avoiding the overhead of a Python loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with numpy built-ins using [broadcasting.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)  Broadcasting allows you to add together two arrays of different shapes without making excessive copies or looping excessively.

We can solve your problem by creating two vectors representing the row and column sums respectively,  and 'multiplying' them together, which will broadcast them into a correctly sized and shaped array.

The best introduction to this topic I know of is the talk [Losing Your Loops: Fast Numerical Computation with Numpy by Jake Vanderplass.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw) It contains visual examples that I find essential for wrapping your head around broadcasting.

Here's a simple example:

IN

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.reshape(np.arange(3), [3, 1])
print('a = ', a)
print('b = ')
print(b)
print('a+b = ')
print(a+b)
```

OUT:

```
a = [0 1 2]
b =
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
a+b =
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

We can solve your problem by creating two vectors representing the row and column sums respectively 'multiplying' them together, broadcasting them into a correctly sized and shaped array.

```
import numpy as np
def gen_expected(array: np.ndarray):
    col_sums = (np.sum(array, axis=0))
    row_sums = np.sum(array, axis=1)
    np.reshape(row_sums, [len(row_sums), 1])
    return (col_sums * row_sums)  / np.sum(array)
# NOTE: this result might be transposed! Check it yourself!
```

Comment: The `keepdims` parameter will let you skip the reshape.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) will compute the `expected` array for you. For example,

```
In [303]: from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

In [304]: a = np.array([[3, 5, 10], [2, 4, 16]])

In [305]: chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(a)

In [306]: expected
Out[306]: 
array([[  2.25,   4.05,  11.7 ],
       [  2.75,   4.95,  14.3 ]])
```

If you only want the `expected` array, you can use [`scipy.stats.contingency.expected_freq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.contingency.expected_freq.html):

```
In [307]: from scipy.stats.contingency import expected_freq

In [308]: expected_freq(a)
Out[308]: 
array([[  2.25,   4.05,  11.7 ],
       [  2.75,   4.95,  14.3 ]])
```

To see how `expected_freq` computes the result, you can see the source code here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/contingency.py

You'll see that the code is vectorized; the only explicit loop is over the number of dimensions of the input array (in the function `margins(a)`).

Answer (score 2):

So with a sample array:

```
In [147]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

and your code:

```
In [148]: def gen_expected(a_array):
     ...:     new_array = np.zeros(a_array.shape,dtype=float)
     ...:     for ri,r in enumerate(a_array):
     ...:         for ci,c in enumerate(a_array.T):
     ...:             new_array[ri,ci]=(c.sum()*r.sum()/a_array.sum())
     ...:     return new_array
     ...: 
In [149]: gen_expected(arr)
Out[149]: 
array([[  1.2       ,   1.4       ,   1.6       ,   1.8       ],
       [  4.4       ,   5.13333333,   5.86666667,   6.6       ],
       [  7.6       ,   8.86666667,  10.13333333,  11.4       ],
       [ 10.8       ,  12.6       ,  14.4       ,  16.2       ]])
```

The only element level, or scalar, step in your function is a 3 term product and division:

```
In [151]: def chi0(csum, rsum, asum):
     ...:     return csum*rsum/asum
```

which we can 'wrap' in vectorize:

```
In [152]: fchi0 = np.vectorize(chi0, otypes=[float])
```

`vectorize` does a nice job of broadcasting arrays against each other, and feeding the results to your function.  In effect it can perform the row and column enumerations.  We just need to take the relevant sums:

```
In [153]: fchi0(arr.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True), arr.sum(axis=0,keepdims=True), arr.sum())
Out[153]: 
array([[  1.2       ,   1.4       ,   1.6       ,   1.8       ],
       [  4.4       ,   5.13333333,   5.86666667,   6.6       ],
       [  7.6       ,   8.86666667,  10.13333333,  11.4       ],
       [ 10.8       ,  12.6       ,  14.4       ,  16.2       ]])
```

But with those 3 sums, I don't need to use the `vectorize` intermediary:

```
In [154]: arr.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)* arr.sum(axis=0,keepdims=True) / arr.sum()

Out[154]: 
array([[  1.2       ,   1.4       ,   1.6       ,   1.8       ],
       [  4.4       ,   5.13333333,   5.86666667,   6.6       ],
       [  7.6       ,   8.86666667,  10.13333333,  11.4       ],
       [ 10.8       ,  12.6       ,  14.4       ,  16.2       ]])

In [155]: arr.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True), arr.sum(axis=0,keepdims=True), arr.sum()
Out[155]: 
(array([[ 6],
        [22],
        [38],
        [54]]), 
 array([[24, 28, 32, 36]]), 
 120)
```

The key to the broadcasting is creating a column vector, a row vector, and total sum (scalar).  One is (4,1) in shape, the other (1,4).  The `keepdims` parameter keeps the 2d shape.  Without it we'd have to add a dimension to the first.  (4,) broadcasts to (1,4), but to (4,1) requires explicit ok.

When generating indices, e.g. `np.arange(4)`, `np.ix_` is a handy tool

```
In [156]: np.ix_(arr.sum(axis=1), arr.sum(axis=0))
Out[156]: 
(array([[ 6],
        [22],
        [38],
        [54]]), array([[24, 28, 32, 36]]))
```

And before `keepdims` was added, adding dimensions with `np.newaxis` was - and still is - a favorite:

```
In [157]: arr.sum(axis=1)[:,None] * arr.sum(axis=0) / arr.sum()
Out[157]: 
array([[  1.2       ,   1.4       ,   1.6       ,   1.8       ],
       [  4.4       ,   5.13333333,   5.86666667,   6.6       ],
       [  7.6       ,   8.86666667,  10.13333333,  11.4       ],
       [ 10.8       ,  12.6       ,  14.4       ,  16.2       ]])
```

More generally `ix_` is recommended when generating indices from ranges;

```
In [160]: I,J = np.ix_(range(10,40,10), range(1,5))
In [161]: I+J
Out[161]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [31, 32, 33, 34]])
```