# Python Numpy Matrix Apply Element Row Column Entry Wise Function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, lambda

I want to apply a function on every `(i,j)` entry of a `NumPy` matrix. But I want to use the values `i` and `j`. As an example, given vectors `A` and `B`, and an abstract function `f`, I want to do the following:

```
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        M[i,j] = f(A[i],B[j])
```

Instead of the above can i do something like the following:

```
g = lambda (i,j): f(A[i],B[j])
apply(M, g)
```

Just trying to vectorize the `for` loops.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you can try it in your box, then try to debug it if you encounter any problems.

Comment: If you're used to R, you may be used to using the `apply` family of functions to apply a computation over a data structure. I don't know how R implements that, but that kind of thing isn't efficient in NumPy. Efficient array manipulation in NumPy usually consists of using operations and functions that handle array input natively.

Comment: You can hide the operation in function, but that won't speed it up - the barrier is the abstract function `f` that can only take and produce scalar values.  The code still has to call that function once for each element in `M`.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170231/functional-programming-numpy-vectorizable-function-to-create-an-expected-values

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the function

```
f = lambda x, y: x ** 2 + y

np.random.seed([3,1415])
A = np.random.rand(10)
B = np.random.rand(10)
M = np.empty_like(A)
M.fill(np.nan)

slc = np.array([3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Then doing what you proposed

```
M[slc] = f(A[slc], B[slc])

M

array([        nan,         nan,         nan,  1.14332569,         nan,
        0.11791531,  0.86916307,  0.86854943,         nan,         nan])

​
```